# Python: Convince Decimal to not use the E notation

Tags: python, decimal

How can I get rid of this rewriting?

```
In [38]: Decimal('0.000000000000001')
Out[38]: Decimal('1E-15')
```

Comment: did you try a search before posting?

Comment: Considering that the linked question is for floats and the accepted answer is float-specific, it's not a great dupe candidate. Using the accepted answer directly actually causes precision loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `format` on the number with the `f` presentation type, which requests fixed-point notation, does what you want:

```
>>> x = decimal.Decimal('0.000000000000000001')
>>> x
Decimal('1E-18')
>>> format(x, 'f')
'0.000000000000000001'
```

Note that `format(Decimal(str(a)).normalize(), 'f')` isn't what you want, because `Decimal(str(a))` is unnecessary and `normalize` may drop precision:

```
>>> x = decimal.Decimal('1.234123412341234123412341234123412341')
>>> x.normalize()
Decimal('1.234123412341234123412341234')
```